# CodeIgniter refresh page after form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to refresh a page via CodeIgniter, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Basically, we have a list of jobs on a page and a user has the option to filter the said jobs.

So, a user will select checkboxes and then click save to save their selections to a database based on their user id.

I will obviously need the data to refresh once they have saved their selection, but I have tried many things and this doesn't seem to work at all. I assume I've got the redirect in the wrong place, which is currently in the controller.

I've tried the following:

```
    $this->load->helper('url');

    redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
```

But nothing happens.

I have the above redirect in the controller function:

```
        public function save_filters() {    

        if (isset($_POST)){
            $filters = $_POST['client_ids'];
        }   

        $this->load->model('dashboard_model');  
        $this->dashboard_model->update_dashboard_filters($filters);

         $this->load->helper('url');

        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');

    }
```

Did I put it in the wrong place?

I get no errors or warnings from firebug?

The form:

```
            <form id="filters_form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="GAB Robins">GAB Robins </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="4">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Cunningham Lindsay">Cunningham Lindsay </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="5">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Lloyds">Lloyds </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="7">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Sundry/Private">Sundry/Private </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="9">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="WNS Ltd">WNS Ltd </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="4441">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Stream">Stream </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="4493">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="Redesign">Redesign </label><input type="checkbox" name="client_ids[]" value="5295">
                    </td>                                                                                                                       
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Save selections" name="save_filters" id="save_filters_button" />
        </form>
```

The javascript that deals with the form

```
        save_filter: function () {
        $.post('/dashboard/save_filters', $('#filters_form').serialize(), function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'ok') {
                if ($('.ui-success').length == 0) {
                    $('#page_main').before('<div class="ui-success" style="margin-bottom: 1em; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 1em;"><img src="/common/images/icons/accept.png" style="margin-right: 10px;" align="absmiddle" />Filters saved!</div>').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            }
            else {
                $(response.errors).each(function (i, item) {
                    alert(item);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Form added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the action in form 
`action="<?php base_url(); ?>controller_name/function_name"` and `method="post"`

Example:

```
 <form id="filters_form"  action="<?php base_url(); ?>controller_name/function_name" method="post">
```

**UPDATE:** Because you are using JS, you are not refreshing page. Don't use JS if you want to refresh the page.

Comment: The form works though, it updates the database. I've added the javascript that deals with the form into the main post

Comment: Great, thank you. That worked submitting the form to the function rather than via javascript!

Comment: @frobak you also can redirect with JS if you want, but with form is faster and better. Accept question if it help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you have an Ajax request, and you cant make redirect on server before you return data to JavaScript that made that request.

you can make redirect based on your response